# send each array element to database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array like this

```
$a = scandir($dir)
```

It contains a list of folders in a directory. How can I store each element of the array as a new record in a database table? The only methods I have found so far convert the array to one long string.

I have tried

```
foreach($array as $item)
send each item to database
```

But I receive the error " Notice: Undefined variable"

Full Code

```
$dir = "/some/folder";

// Sort in ascending order
$a = scandir($dir);

$string_version = implode(',', $a);

$array = explode(' ', $string_version);


foreach($array as $item)
{


$dbcon="INSERT INTO $DBTable(Column) VALUES('$item')";


}

?>
```

Comment: What exactly you tried? Code you given? You should try `foreach($dir as $item) { functionSendidngItem($item) }`.

Comment: There's a lot more to that error message (like the undefined variable name, file and line number, etc). Why would you omit such vital details from your question?

Comment: edited post with more code

Answer (score 3):

`$array` is not defined. Your array variable is called `$a`.

Answer (score 0):

scandir() returns an array already, why are you converting it to a string then back to an array?
also your new array will be undefined because the delimiters are different.

This should be sufficient to iterate through the array results:

```
$dir = "/some/folder";

// Sort in ascending order
$array = scandir($dir);

foreach($array as $item)
{


$dbcon="INSERT INTO $DBTable(Column) VALUES('$item')";
/*
I AM ASSUMING THAT YOU UNDERSTAND THAT YOUR SQL QUERY IS NOT DOING ANYTHING YET since you haven't called mysqli_query();
Also - have you defined the connection??
*/


}

?>
```